# Getting unrealistic values with dht22 even though the bits it sends are right when looked at with an oscilloscope

Tags: c, codeblocks, stm32

I am using a STM32F407 microcontroller with the program CodeBlocks and i am trying to use the DHT22 temperature and humidity sensor. There are probably other posts like this but I looked at all of them (at least all I found) but not a single one of them could help me, so I thought I would ask it here. My code should be working until the point where I have to read the data, I think I am messing something up with the timings, because the DHT22 is very time sensitive with his protocol. But I have tried different things and nothing worked.

Here is my code:

```
#include "SmartcontrolOS.h"
#include "Apps.h"

void Temperature_Humidity(ui32 dt){

    static bool ini_OK = false;

    if(!ini_OK) Scheduler__wait(_,3*sec); // start signal block

    DO__write_open_drain(_,PA4,1);
    DO__write_open_drain(_,PA4,0);
    Scheduler__wait(_,10*ms);
    DO__write_open_drain(_,PA4,1);
    Scheduler__wait(_,40*us);
    DI__read(_,PA4);

    Scheduler__wait(_,40*us);            //check sensor reply block

    if(DI__read(_,PA4) == 0)  Scheduler__wait(_,90*us);

    while(DI__read(_,PA4) == 0) ;

    ui8 sum;
    ui8 temp1, temp2;
    ui8 feucht1, feucht2;
    int i;

    for(i = 40; i > 0; i = i - 1)  //read data block
    {
        if( i > 32)
        {
            while (DI__read(_,PA4) != 1);

            Scheduler__wait(_,40*us);

           if(DI__read(_,PA4) == 0)      feucht1 = feucht1 | (0 << (i - 32));
           if(DI__read(_,PA4) == 1)      feucht1 = feucht1 | (1 << (i - 32));

           while(DI__read(_,PA4) == 0) ;
        }
        else if( i > 23 && i < 33)
        {
            while (DI__read(_,PA4) != 1) ;
            Scheduler__wait(_,40*us);

            if(DI__read(_,PA4) == 0)      feucht2 = feucht2 | (0 << (i - 24));
            if(DI__read(_,PA4) == 1)      feucht2 = feucht2 | (1 << (i - 24));

            while(DI__read(_,PA4) == 0) ;
        }
        else if(i > 15 && i < 25)
        {
            while (DI__read(_,PA4) != 1) ;

            Scheduler__wait(_,50*us);

            if(DI__read(_,PA4) == 0)       temp1 = temp1 | (0 << (i-16));
            if(DI__read(_,PA4) == 1)       temp1 = temp1 | (1 << (i-16));

            while(DI__read(_,PA4) == 0) ;
        }
        else if( i > 9 && i < 17 )
        {
            while (DI__read(_,PA4) != 1) ;

            Scheduler__wait(_,50*us);

            if(DI__read(_,PA4) == 0)       temp2 = temp2 | (0 << (i-8));
            if(DI__read(_,PA4) == 1)       temp2 = temp2 | (1 << (i-8));

            while(DI__read(_,PA4) == 0) ;
        }
        else
        {
            while (DI__read(_,PA4) != 1) ;

            Scheduler__wait(_,40*us);

            if(DI__read(_,PA4) == 0)      sum = sum | 0 << (i);
            else                          sum = sum | 1 << (i);

            while(DI__read(_,PA4) == 0) ;
        }
    }

    ui16 Temperature, RH;

    RH = (feucht1 << 8) | feucht2;

    Temperature = (temp1 << 8) | temp2;

    LCD__write(_,"%8.1f\n%8.1f   %5.0f",
        wf(RH/10.0f),
        wf(Temperature/10.0f),
        wf(sum));

    Scheduler__wait(_,3*sec);
    ini_OK = true;
}

void CPE_App__Wetterstation_T_RH(){

    Resources__ExBoard_init(_,"");

    while(1){
        const ui32 dt = 1*ms;
        Scheduler__wait(_,dt);

        Temperature_Humidity(dt);
   }
}
```

The humidity value would rarely change at all with a stable value of 4369.5 and if it changed only behind the comma and the temperature value would be about 2700 and when I would get some heat to the sensor it would jump to 4500 and then drop down to 2700 again.

Comment: I don't know this microcontroller, but I wonder if there's an issue with the bit-fiddling in each of the `if` tests.  If `DI__read` returns a 1 it's clear that you're OR'ing in a bit, but for a zero it does nothing. Are you trying to turn *off* the bit? In that case, it would be something like: `temp2 = temp2 & ~(  1 << (i-8))`

Comment: Also: do you really intend to call `DI__read()` twice in most of the cases, or could you do a single read in the bottom and allow the `else` to handle the other case.

Comment: Also, the `if` tests only really need a greater-than test, the loop is counting down, and previous tests will catch the greater-than cases.

Comment: Also, all the running totals (`temp1`, `temp2`, etc.) are uninitialized and possibly filled with junk before the loop even starts

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the comments on my previous answer I'm going to suggest a second approach for the OP. This is not about temperature or humidity, but about serial communications and getting the timings right.

The specs for the DHT22 say we have to essentially clock in 40 bits of data with a specific timing pattern, and those bits split up into 5 bytes with meanings you care about later, but not until you can read them properly.

So: I propose creating a test program that does nothing but clock those 40 bits into an `unsigned long long` so it's treated as unitary item and not temp or humidity or whatever. Then you can run the code and compare the resulting bits with what you see on the scope.

Once you've configured your port for this special communications mode, you have to then watch the port to determine each bit's value.

ASCII art is always awesome on the web, but I can try showing two different waveforms that represent the two possible values.

EVERY bit starts with a High->Low transition that you synchronize against by waiting for a LOW signal on the port. I've marked it position A.

```
            A          B         C      B
    ________            _____    .       ___...
            |          |     |   .      |
            v  start   ^  0  |   .      ^
            |__________|     |___.______|
                                                 B
    ________            _________.____           ___...
            |          |         .    |          |
            v  start   ^      1  .    |          |
            |__________|         .    |__________|
```

Once you get the sync signal at A, you immediately wait for it to go back high again to start the data, that's position B. It's going to always take 50 msec, but you're not measuring that - you're only waiting for it to happen.

Once you're at position B, the data bit, the device will hold high for ~25 msec for a zero bit, but ~70 msec for a one bit. So: if we check ~40 msec after it goes high, we will know the value of the bit.

This is shown as position C with a dotted line; it could be 35 msec or 50 msec, I just chose 40 to be in the middle.

In any case, once you have recorded the bit, you start the loop again by waiting for the High-to-low transition (position A, which might have already happened), then the low-to-high (position B, which is the *next* data bit).

Note: you do not have to wait for any high/low bit position at the end of the loop because it's all handled properly at the *top* of the loop.

And even though you'll be reading 40 bits, it's easier to break this up into a byte at a time. This is why I asked about `unsigned long long` (which would be big enough) but decided this wasn't necessary after all.

```
// clock in the next 8 bits from the sensor
ui8 readSensorByte(void)
{
    ui8 b = 0;

    for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        while (DI__read(_,PA4) != 0) ;  // wait for SYNC (A)
        while (DI__read(_,PA4) != 1) ;  // wait for DATA (B)

        Scheduler__wait(_, 40*us);

        if (DI__read(_, PA4)) // if we see a one bit
            b |= 1 << i;
    }

    return b;
}
```

Then call this as part of your larger routine; I'll let you sort out the setup parts.

```
void Temperature_Humidity(ui32 dt){
    // setup the port

    // flip the bits to tell the device to start sending

    // Now read 40 bits 8 at a time
    ui8 feucht1 = readSensorByte();
    ui8 feucht2 = readSensorByte();
    ui8 temp1   = readSensorByte();
    ui8 temp2   = readSensorByte();
    ui8 sum     = readSensorByte();

    // compute and display results
}
```

It's important that even though we are reading 8 bits at a time, all 5 calls have to be made right in a row so 40 bits arrive in line: once it starts transmitting, it's not going to finish until all 40 are out.

Comment: I tried this and all the ui8 variables have now the value of 255 when i display them on my LCD. I also had to change the line     ```while (DI__read(_,PA4) != 0);``` to 
 ```while (DI__read(_,PA4) == 0)``` because otherwise i would have a endless loop.

Comment: So if i understand correctly you say that i should write a programm that shoves the 40 bits into a unsinged long long variable but i dont really understand what you you mean with
 "Then you can run the code and compare the resulting bits with what you see on the scope."
From what i understood i create a '''unsigned long long''' variable and shove my 40 bits in there and then i compare the bits i have into this varaible with the bits i see on an osziolloscope.

Comment: My original thought was to just read it all into an unsigned long long for simplicity, but later realized I didn't have to do that when I (thought I) had a good handle on the protocol.  At this point I'm not sure what's left to advise.

Comment: It is just weird that all the things you advised me and that i tried are not working because most of those methods are just resembling existing programs in the internet of this sensor. I will maybe try some more things and if nothing works i have to get another sensor. Thank you for your help so far Mister Steve Friedl.

Comment: One other thing I'd try if it were on my bench: if you have another I/O port available, use it for *output* and measure it as a second trace on the scope. Every time you poll the input pin (after the 40msc wait), strobe the second I/O port - this will show you the data coming from the device on the first trace, and when you're sampling each bit in the second trace. Then make sure the numbers your code is getting matches where the traces show you sample.  Maybe this will help you sort it out?

Comment: Before i move on and buy another sensor i wanna ask one more thing. In the datasheet it says the sensor first sends out 8 bit integral humidity and then 8 bit decimal humidity and then 8 bit integral temp and 8 bit decima temp. What does integral and decimal mean in this sentence?
Datasheet: https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Temperature/DHT22.pdf

Comment: I forgot to add it is under point 6. Operating specifications.

Comment: I'd like to recommend that rather than figure out what the bits mean (though of course you have to do that eventually), first figure out if you're even getting the *right* bits.  Run your program and have it print the binary values of each of the 5 items, then compare those with what you see on the scope: you don't know if you're just confused about the bit patterns, or if you're not even capturing them correctly.

Comment: I can do the bool part but using an oscilloscop will be rather difficult because i now have Christmas Holiday and the oscilloscopes are in my school but i could just figure out the bit patern because i know how it looks, i mean i already made some experiements in school with the bit patterns

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulating a bunch of things from comments above, this might simplify the code a bit. None of this is tested, I don't know the microcontroller.

Simplified the `if` tests, moved the common busy-wait on `PA4` to outside the if/else, changed the bit-fiddling to be more what I suspect you wanted, plus initialized the values you're building up as you go along.

```
void Temperature_Humidity(ui32 dt){

    static bool ini_OK = false;

    if(!ini_OK) Scheduler__wait(_,3*sec); // start signal block

    DO__write_open_drain(_,PA4,1);
    DO__write_open_drain(_,PA4,0);
    Scheduler__wait(_,10*ms);
    DO__write_open_drain(_,PA4,1);
    Scheduler__wait(_,40*us);
    DI__read(_,PA4);

    Scheduler__wait(_,40*us);            //check sensor reply block

    if(DI__read(_,PA4) == 0)  Scheduler__wait(_,90*us);

    while(DI__read(_,PA4) == 0) ;

    // all must be initialized to zero!
    ui8 sum = 0;
    ui8 temp1 = 0, temp2 = 0;
    ui8 feucht1 = 0, feucht2 = 0;

    int i;

    for(i = 39; i >= 0; i--)  //read data block
    {
        while (DI__read(_,PA4) != 1) ;  // busy wait

        Scheduler__wait(_, 40*us);

        if (DI__read(_, PA4))
        {
            if     (i >= 32) feucht1 |= 1 << (i - 32);
            else if(i >= 24) feucht2 |= 1 << (i - 24);
            else if(i >= 16) temp1   |= 1 << (i - 16);
            else if(i >=  8) temp2   |= 1 << (i -  8);
            else             sum     |= 1 << i;
        }

        while(DI__read(_,PA4) == 0) ;  // busy wait
    }

    ui16 Temperature, RH;

    RH = (feucht1 << 8) | feucht2;

    Temperature = (temp1 << 8) | temp2;

    LCD__write(_,"%8.1f\n%8.1f   %5.0f",
        wf(RH/10.0f),
        wf(Temperature/10.0f),
        wf(sum));

    Scheduler__wait(_,3*sec);
    ini_OK = true;
}
```

I also believe the numeric values that the if/else chain is running against is off by one, because it's going from 40 down to 1, and the last block of the `else` is when i = 8 or less.  The problem is, if i=8 then `sum = sum | 1 << 8`; will produce a value that won't fit in the target 8-bit value `sum`.

So I adjusted all the tests so that each block addresses 8 bits at a time with - I hope - the proper offsets and changed the loop to go from 39 --> 0 instead of 40 --> 1

**EDIT** The more I looked at this the more I was able to figure out what it's doing, clocking in one bit at a time, and this let me dramatically simplify the code.

When it polls the bit, we don't have to do *anything* if it's a zero because we can rely on the initialized zero of the variable being assigned to.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer i will try it first thing tomorrow and then i will share if it works or not.

Comment: I tried your solution but now my humidity is stuck at 2184.6 and my temperature is in between 4681.0 and 5700.0. I thought maybe the problem has to do with the timing because i i read that the timing has to be really precise for this specific one wire protocol otherwise it wont work. This suspicion has also been kinda confirmned for me because the "feucht1" ,which translates to humidity1, byte should rarely ever be teh value 1 because when its really moist the 512 value bit is 1. But i also dont know how i could improve on timings. SO im asking for help once again.

Comment: This site, https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/DHT22_Temperature-Humidity_Sensor, explains the specific protocol for this sensor rather well. Here is the datasheet of the sensor i forgot to add it at first, https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/Digital+humidity+and+temperature+sensor+AM2302.pdf

Comment: Do we know if the ARM can do 64-bit integer arithmetic? Is `unsigned long long` supported?

Comment: I mean i dont really know how to check it but i typed 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 in a unsigned long long variable and no warnings came and when i wrote 9,223,372,036,854,775,808 a warning came so it works in codeblocks so it probably works with my mikrocontroller. What do i have to do with it?